# Groupby and create a new column by randomly assign multiple strings into it in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have students infos `id`, `age` and `class` as follows:

```
   id  age  class
0   1   23    a
1   2   24    a
2   3   25    b
3   4   22    b
4   5   16    c
5   6   16    d
```

I want to groupby `class` and create a new column named `major` by randomly assign `math, art, business, science` into it, which means for same class, the major strings are same.

We may need to use `apply(lambda x: random.choice..)` to realize this, but I don't know how to do this. Thanks for your help.

Output expected:

```
   id  age     major  class
0   1   23       art    a
1   2   24       art    a
2   3   25   science    b
3   4   22   science    b
4   5   16  business    c
5   6   16      math    d
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I haven't found this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html?highlight=choice#numpy.random.choice) with number of values by length of `DataFrame`:

```
df['major'] = np.random.choice(['math', 'art', 'business', 'science'], size=len(df))
print (df)
   id  age     major
0   1   23  business
1   2   24       art
2   3   25   science
3   4   22      math
4   5   16   science
5   6   16  business
```

EDIT: for same major values per groups use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary:

```
c = df['class'].unique()
vals = np.random.choice(['math', 'art', 'business', 'science'], size=len(c))

df['major'] = df['class'].map(dict(zip(c, vals)))
print (df)
   id  age class     major
0   1   23     a  business
1   2   24     a  business
2   3   25     b       art
3   4   22     b       art
4   5   16     c   science
5   6   16     d      math
```

Comment: Thanks, I have modified my question, could you retake a look please?